# Angular animation based on conditional content in component

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I know how to do an angular animation, but this time I have a component that has no specified height (it sizes based on what's inside the component).  There is already content of varying height in the instances of the component.  On click, it displays additional content below (i.e. "product details"), shown with an `ngIf` linked to a toggling variable `showDetails` which is a boolean.

Showing this makes the component markedly taller.

Is there a way I can animate this transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `*ngIf` and control the visibility of the content through animation alone. Try the following:

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('displayState', [
      state('false', style({ overflow: 'hidden', height: '0px'})),
      state('true', style({ overflow: 'hidden', height: '*'})),
      transition('false => true', animate('200ms ease-in')),
      transition('true => false', animate('200ms ease-out'))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  display = false;

  toggle() {
    this.display = !this.display;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<button (mouseup)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<br><br>

<div [@displayState]="display" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': '#ff000050'}">
  <p>Dynamic content</p>
  <p>that is controlled</p>
  <p>by animation alone</p>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5netne)

**Update**

You could use the existing boolean `showDetails` to show additional content with a transition. Again it replaces the `*ngIf` with only the animation. Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwa1e3)

Comment: That's cool, but my component has variable-height content already; I am just adding _additional_ content.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The answer could be adapted to your requirement. I've posted an update. Please check if it works for you.